# Can't sign into an iPhone 4 to set it up as a new device - stuck in a loop

Tags: iphone, security

When I sign into an iPhone 4 to set it up as a new device, my other Apple devices receive a prompt to allow the sign-in, I click yes, then receive a 6 number code.

However, on my iPhone 4, I am still presented with the username/password prompt, and if I click Next, it prompts another security prompt on my other Apple devices, so I am stuck in a loop.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke to Apple who confirmed Apple 2FA requires iOS 9 or greater.

iPhone 4 has iOS 7, so there is no way to sign into the Apple ID.